# Using Laravel with() and all()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I have this model called ProductLog.php

```
class ProductLog extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes, LogsActivity;

protected $table = 'product_logs';

protected static $logAttributes = ['name'];

protected static $logName = 'product_logs';

public function getDescriptionForEvent(string $eventName): string
{
    return "Product Log has been {$eventName}";
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'product_id',
    'json_data',
    'type',
    'name',
    'is_active'
];

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Services\Products\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Services\Users\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}

}
```

and in query I'm using this command to get the data of my table ProductLog

```
public function fetchAll() 
{
    return $this->model->with('product','user')->get();
}
```

I'm using **get();** on my query, is it possible to switch from **get();** to **all();**

Comment: Short: No.
This is because `Model::all()` is a static method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, the function looks as follows:

`return static::query()->get(...)`

Comment: The real question is why? Using `get` with no additional query constraints is equivalent to using `all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

[`all()` is a method on a `Model`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all), which returns a `Collection`, which doesn't have a `with()` method.

[`with()` is a method on a `Model`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with), which returns a `Builder`, which doesn't have an `all()` method.

Because `all()` and `with()` are both `Model` methods, you can't chain them together.

`with()->get()` is the correct chain to use, and should give you the result you want.